# phpMyAdmin, can not login to root user

Tags: mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin, mariadb, ubuntu-16.04

I just went through setting up a LEMP stack on my server and I then installed phpMyAdmin. It looks like I can not login due to the method the root user uses to connect.

This is the warning I get while checking the status of the mysql service

- 1:26:01 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' has both a password and an authentication plugin specified. The password will be ignored.

This is the error I receive on the phpMyAdmin webpage

- 1698 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the issue by executing

```
sudo mysql -u root
update user set plugin='' where User='root';
```

Comment: this did not fix the issue for me.